# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {inputList}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, next.js

I was trying object to create input fields using key and value pair. I thought it would be a breeze but I am getting this error. I find no easy way of doing this thing but this.

```
import {Form, Input, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const input = [{
    name: 'Full Name', 
    dob: 'Date of Birth', 
    parentName: "Father's/Mother's Name", 
    email: "Email",
    mobile: "Mobile Number",
    password: "Password",
    rePassword: "Re-enter Password",
    aadhar: "Aadhar Number"
}]

// const inputList = ["Full Name", "Date of Birth", "Father's/Mother's Name", "Email", "Mobile Number","Password", "Re-enter Password", "Aadhar"]

let inputList = [];

for(let key in input) {
    inputList.push(<Form.Field name={key} key={key} control={Input} label={input[key]} />)
}

const RegistrationForm = () => {
    return(
        <Form>
            <Form.Field name="name" control={Input} placeholder='Full Name' label='Full Name:'/>
            {
                {inputList}
                // inputList.map((input,index) => {
                //     return(<Form.Field key={index} control={Input} label={input}/>)
                // })
            }
        </Form>
    )
}

export default RegistrationForm
```

So what I am trying to do here is, create an object where my key would be the name of the form field and the value would be the label. To use that I was using `for` loop but I am getting the above mentioned error. How to resolve this ? If not, is there any other way to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when rendering to the DOM, React will convert JSX to HTML DOM element (you can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)). So anything inside the curly bracket, React will assume that it is embedded JS code that is expecting to return JSX, an Array of JSX or a value. By doing `{{inputList}}` what you are trying to do is telling React to render a JS Object with key, ES6 syntax which you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions), `inputList` into the DOM which fundamentally illegal to do so in React. So since you're already do the creation of JSX for each element in `inputList` in your `for` loop, you can just do `{inputList}` instead like this:

```js
const RegistrationForm = () => {
    return(
        <Form>
            <Form.Field name="name" control={Input} placeholder='Full Name' label='Full Name:'/>
            {inputList}
        </Form>
    )
}
```

On another note, if you don't want to use `for` loop, what you can do instead is this:

```js
let inputList = Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => (<Form.Field name={key} key={key} control={Input} label={value} />));
```

You can read more on `Object.entries` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)